# VSCode no intellisense in haskell extension for additional modules

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-stack

Is there a way to make intellisense work for additional modules (anything outside the prelude) like Quicktest or Random in VS Code?
I am using:

- VSCode: Version 1.55.0
- the extension "Haskell v1.2.0" (with haskel-language-server)
- ghci: `GHCi, version 8.10.3: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/`
- stack: `Version 2.5.1, Git revision d6ab861544918185236cf826cb2028abb266d6d5 x86_64 hpack-0.33.0`
- tried it direct on Windows10 and with WSL2 (Debian).

VSCode says:

```
Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’
It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.not found
```

[image]
So, no autocomplete etc..

I think the reason is that I've installed Quicktest via `stack`, and that stack uses its own "isolated" ghc. So I looked for a way to configure the VSCode extension to use the ghc of my `stack` environment, without success.

I've also tingled with haddock and cabal, without success.

Does anybody using VS-Code to code haskell and have autocomplete, documentation on mouse over, wingman, ...?

Comment: I think the problem is that the LSP plugin cannot extract dependencies in the test suite. One rather annoying workaround I found is to move test dependencies into global dependencies in package.yaml. Another is to [generate an hie.yaml](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/hcu5sf/mystified_by_hieyaml/), e.g. using [implicit-hie](https://github.com/Avi-D-coder/implicit-hie), so that packages in multiple sub-components are recognized.

Comment: @Simon Shine implicit-hie is cool and solve my environment management 
problem, but my main problem is that intellisense in VSCode
not supporting anything outside the prelude (like random, quicktest, ...), added a screenshot to question.

Comment: Are you saying that VSCode does not support anything outside Prelude *in the test suite*, or *in general*?

Comment: In general. I have no autocomplete etc. in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm now revisiting haskell: The current `VSCode Version 1.83.1` with the haskell extension `Haskell 2.4.2`. Autocomplete etc. are working fine.

Go to project folder init stack and install a package:

```
init stack
stack install split
```

Restart VScode for an implicit GHC restart. Afterwards everything works as expected see below:

[image: VSCode showing package doc]

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem with some local modules. I was able to fix it by placing a `hie.yaml` file in the project's root directory and reloading VSCode. Admittedly I don't really know what it does. I generated it using [implicit-hie](https://github.com/Avi-D-coder/implicit-hie) which you can install with `stack`.

Comment: I've already tried that, after @ Simon Shine pointed that out, it works for local modules, but not for "third party stuff", did you get autocomplete + no errors in the vs code editor when you import ```Random``` ...

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have completely glossed over that... I see what you mean now. I tried importing `System.Random` and it tells me that it's from a hidden package. I was able to get it fully working by adding `random` to the `build-depends` entry in my .`cabal` file and reloading. I also ran `stack install random` just in case?

Comment: I've now tried stack + hie.yaml, + cabal. Installed random and/or added random as package ... yes it compiles and yes it runs. But the situation in the editor is still the same ... no autocomplete, no documtention on mouse hover (wingman), and the errors in output. Do you have "editor support" in VS-Code?

Comment: @Kraego, did you ever find a solution? I am facing the same issues currently

Comment: @sss, I didn't found a solution